# Getting child input from div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, parent-child

I have a repeater that has a UserControl inside it that shows me 3 security questions like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptSecurityQuestions">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <it:TextBoxControl_v2
            ID="txtQuestion"
            runat="server"
            ShowLabel="true"
            MinLength="1"
            MaxLength="64"
            Label='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "question") %>'
            RegexExpression=""
            TextMode="SingleLine"
            CssClass="field field-padding-r metro col-centered securityQuestions"
            IsRequired="true" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And it displays like this 3 times:

```
    <div class="securityQuestions">
        <span>Question 1</span>
      <input></input>
    </div>
```

all i want is to get the inputs that are child of my div.

I tried something like this but it didn't work out.

```
$(this).children('securityQuestions').addClass('hover_triangle');
```

Comment: You can try: `$('.securityQuestions').find('input').addClass('hover_triangle');`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple typo error

Specify its a class by prefixing `.`

```
   $(this).find('.securityQuestionsinput[type="text"]').addClass('hover_triangle');
```

if you want to apply the class to parent of the input element use below

```
$(this).find('.securityQuestionsinput[type="text"]').parent().addClass('hover_triangle');
```

Demo:

```js
$('#test').find('.test input[type="text"]').addClass('hover_triangle');
```

```css
.hover_triangle{background-color:red}
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div id="test">
         <div class="test"><input type="text"></div>
         <div class="test">2</div>
         <div class="test">3</div>
         <div class="test">4</div>
         <div class="test">5</div>
         <div class="test">6</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: but if i make it like this it applies to all childs and i only want the input's